# Unity is not loading correctly

Tags: unity, nvidia, unity-2d, vaio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and it was working well. But right now when I try to start my session with Unity it loads incorrectly. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

No sidebar, no toolbar. However, when I start a session selecting Unity 2D it loads correctly. What is the problem?

Note, that I am using Sony VAIO laptop with nVidia GeForce of 1Gb memory and all the controllers and drivers for nVidia GeForce are installed correctly.

Thank you,
Bak

**update 1**

When I try `unity --reset` command it gives following warning message `I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/jhon/.compiz/session/102b9a8b904eafa80213192505537390400000017880001"`. In reality there is no any folder called .compiz in my home directory, instead of that folder I have `compiz-1` folder.