# Ubuntu gets stuck on desktop screen?

Tags: 11.10, installation, launcher, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I have an Acer Aspire One, running Ubuntu 11.10 I recently installed Ubuntu, because my Windows XP was real buggy. I came across this problem, where once I reboot and login, I cannot see anything, not even the launcher! I reinstalled Ubuntu and it started working fine. After some experimenting, it seemed that If I don't logout and shutdown, this happens. Has anyone encountered this problem? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: See my answer to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/70494/unity-is-not-loading-correctly