# after 11.10 update and compiz install, desktop vanished - only functional keys are ctrl-alt-del

Tags: unity

Yesterday I updated from 10.04 to 11.10 and ended up with the Unity desktop. I was slowly getting the hang of it but wanted to make the launcher icons smaller. I installed Compiz per the help page, ran it, but couldn't figure out how to change the icon size. I closed the application and everything on the desktop vanished. I tried pressing the meta key twice (Windows key according to the help page) but nothing happened. Same for the alt keys (both of them) and the menu key. The only key combination that did anything (that I could find) was ctrl-alt-del which allowed me to log off and then I was able to shutdown.

What do I do to a) recover a working interface or b) startup in something other than Unity?

Comment: What is 10? Whats is 11.11?. You have Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10, 11.04 and 11.10.

Comment: (You can't comment on your own post because you seem to be using 2 different accounts, I've flagged your accounts to be merged though so that should be fixed soon).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you disabled the unity plugin. This sometimes happen. Now do the following:

- Restart your computer (if necessary, by cutting the power off)
- On the login screen, select "Ubuntu 2D"
- Open Compiz
- Reactivate the Unity plugin
- Restart your computer
- On the login screen, select "Ubuntu"

This should solve your Problem. If not, leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to this question [Unity is not loading correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70494/unity-is-not-loading-correctly/70542#70542.)

If you disable the Unity plugin in Compiz Settings Manager you will not be able to load the Unity Shell.