# Unity session fails to open

Tags: 11.10, unity, startup

While looking out to solve another problem, I've disturbed the opening of Unity session by altering (suppresssing) GConf (as suggested somewhere between, Ubuntu doc, forums and Ask Ubuntu) - now Unity opens on my wallpaper, with a top command bar but without panel or launcher, and with mouse arrow replaced by a (Linux) cross ; when I open a terminal, it opens on the desktop directory, and I have to run a `unity --replace` command to get Unity fully up and running.

There must be a small piece of code somewhere that provokes this mess, but I have no idea about where to look or what to look for.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the right answer. Unity works when I launch it manually, but does not start automatically as it should ; instead, ig get the same situation as described in http://askubuntu.com/questions/70494/unity-is-not-loading-correctly - I've tried the unity 2D compiz settings trick, but that has not improved anything - I'll try once again to remove the gconf files - but I've got cold feet on this one because that is what caused the problem in the 1st place...

Comment: Can you edit your question to put all the things you've tried?